# How to route the user-defined docker bridge network out of VPN tunnel?

Tags: networking, docker, vpn, bridge

I am trying to setup a Squid proxy in order to route some sites in my browser (using .pac file) out of VPN (they are unreachable inside the tunnel). For this reason I use Squid proxy docker container inside user-defined bridge network.

However, by default tunnel takes inside whole net of you PC, so every network package is going through the tunnel. The first problem is that the docker network is unreachable, because local nets' requests are requesting local nets of the VPN server. It could be easily solved by using commands

```
ip rule add to 172.18.0.0/16 pref 100 table 1
ip route add table 1 to 172.18.0.0/16 dev br-43cb854b8af8
ip route flush cache
```

`pref` option is needed because VPN creates its own rules as well.

However, the proxy sends request through the tunnel, so requests should be "routed" out of docker network to Ethernet interface of my PC instead of VPN tun0 (VPN interface name)

So, main questions are

1. How exactly works connection between docker virtual bridge interface
   (on a picture docker0) and host's interface eth0. (I was unable to
   find some obvious iptables rules or iproute2 tables to explain that)?
   [image: Docker bridge net structure]
2. How to route connection from bridge network interface to the chosen
   host interface (instead of the standard VPN's tun0)?